# God's Pair of Teffilin

Tags: midrash, tefilin, theology, parashat-ki-tisa

How is it that when Moshe turns his head [not to see God's face](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%9B%D7%92), he sees He's got on [*teffilin*](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=7&format=pdf)? I thought God had no physical form.

Comment: G-d doesn't, and no one said he did.

Comment: We learn in my community that G-d performs all the mitzvot. The gemara discussing G-d's tefillin, including what is written in them, is referenced here: https://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=hashemtefillin

Answer (score 11):

The Torah speaks in allegory.

Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim

Comment: source in moreh?

Comment: Where does the Torah say that Moshe saw God's Tefillin?

Comment: @mevaqesh - The Torah does not mention that Moshe Rabbeinu saw G-d's tefillin, but it does say that he saw "G-d's back." (Shemos 33:18) When taken literally (and the passage should _not_ be taken literally), it would make sense that Moshe would have also seen G-d's tefillin. (Brachos 7b)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is in order to teach us that wearing tefillin is a fulfillment of [וְהָלַכְתָּ בִּדְרָכָיו](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_of_God#Judaism) ([Deuteronomy 28:9](https://www.google.com/search?q=deuteronomy%2028:9)), walking in the ways of God - imitating Him, Who is perfect, in order for us, His creations, to become more perfect, to demonstrate that He is our Creator.

Comment: so God has a form?

Comment: How are you inferring that from what I wrote here?

Comment: You say that God wears Tefillin therefore we should wear tefillin. Sounds like you're understanding it literally that god wears tefillin. You cant wear tefillin unless you have a form.

Comment: @l', It seems that Adam's intention is that just like, for example, we try to imitate God by being kind, for He is kind, we cannot possibly compare our kindness to His. What it means for God to be kind is different than what it means for you or I to be kind. Similarly, the concept of God's wearing tefillin is not to be taken literally, but rather just like in the kindness example, a representation of "the Godly counterpart" to wearing tefillin.

Comment: @jake - You are indeed correct.

Comment: @Vram, not everybody understands RMB"M literally like you seem to do.

Comment: Wouldn't wearing _Tefilin_ in fulfillment of _ve-Halakhta bi-Drakhav_ make the _Mitzvot_  of _Tefilin_ superfluous?

Answer (score 2):

[R. Hai Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hai_Gaon) explains that this obviously cannot mean that Moses actually saw God wearing tefillin. The verse explicitly states that no man can see God and live, and the Talmud cannot disagree with this. Rather, prophets see images in their hearts rather than with their eyes (i.e. God gives them some sort of mental vision), and in this case Moses could have seen in his heart an image of God's glory with tefillin. He then explains that God was showing Moses tefillin in the same way as he showed Moses an image of the Tabernacle (to help him understand it). He concludes that the part of the vision with the tefillin could have been either in Moses's heart or with his eyes, but the part with God's back could only have been in Moses's heart.

**Teshuvot Hagaonim Im Teshuvot U'Pesakim M'Chachmei Provencia #67** (p. 205-207)

> מנין שהקב"ה מניח תפילין שנא' נשבע ה' בימינו ובזרוע עזו ימינו זו תורה שנ' מימינו אש דת למו עוזו אילו תפילין פירשה שהקב"ה מראה כבודו לנביאיו וחסידיו באונתא דליבא כדמות אדם יושב דכתיב ראיתי את ה' יושב על כסא וגו' וכתיב ואראה את ה' יושב על כסא רם ונשא  וכמי שיש לו רגלים דכתיב תחת רגליו כמעשה לבנת הספיר (וכמעשה) וכיון שנודע לנו שהוא מתראה לנביאים בענין הזה נתברר לנו כי זה הראיה האמורה בראיית הלב ולא בראית העין כי לא יתכן להאמר בראיית העין שנראת דמות להקב"ה שנ' ואל מי תדמיון אל ומה דמות תערכו לו אלא ראיה בלב היא כך יתכן להאמר שאיפשר לאדם לראות בראיית הלב דמות כבוד בראש ועליו תפילין והאומר ראיית בראיה הבל היא כדכתיב ולבי ראה הרבה חכמה ודעת כך כונתו ולא ראיית העין ממש שהרי בפירוש אמר הכתוב ודברתי אל הנביאים וביד הנביאים אדמה מלמד שמראה לכל נביא דמיון שיוכל לראותו אבל ראייה ממש חס ושלום שיש מי שעולה על דעתו וכי ר' יצחק חולק על התורה שנ' ולא יראני האדם וחי ובא ר' יצחק ואמר כי נראה הקב"ה ועוד הלא כתיב ויראו את אלהי ישראל ותחת רגליו כמעשה לבנת הספיר הנה מראה הכתוב שראו ובמקרא אחר כתיב ונשמרתם מאד לנפשותיכם כי לא ראיתם כל תמונה ביום דבר ה' אליכם בחורב מתוך האש קשו קרא אהדדי ופרקינן לא קשיא האי קרא דכתיב ויראו את אלהי ישראל ראית הלב והאי דכתיב כי לא ראיתם כל תמונה ראיית העין ומצאנו לשון הקודש שקורא בענין הזה ראיה שבלב שנ' וירא יעקב כי יש שבר במצרים ויעקב לא היה במצרים אלא בארץ כנען וכהנה רבות למביני הדעת יראי השם פחות מזה די (להם) להבין ולידע שאין בכל התלמוד דבר מודיע שיש בישראל נותן דמות לבוראנו ישתבח שמו ויתעלה זכרו אמנם חלוקי לב רשעי ארץ מינים מחפאים דברים לא כן כדי לגנות עצמם מי שפרע מדור המבול יפרע מהם
>
> ומצאנו שהקב"ה ישתבח שמו הראה למשה רבינו תוך הכבוד שאמר הכתוב וראית את אחורי ופני לא יראו כגון מלאך ובראשו תפילין וראה משה רבינו והבין קשר של תפילין ושין של תפילין כענין שהראהו כלי המשכן שנ' ככל אשר אני מראה אתך את תבנית המשכן וזה יתכן למראית [העין ויתכן למראית] הלב אבל זה שכתב וראית את אחורי אינה אלא ראית הלב ועל אותה הראייה שנא' במשה רבינו שראה קשר של תפילין ושין של תפילין עליה אמר ר' יצחק רמז לזה הדבר מן הכתוב מנין ואמר נשבע ה' בימינו וכענין זה חזיון נבואת הנביא יושב ער ורואה בלבו חזון נבואה כמו ראיית הישן חלום ומקרא מלא כתיב אם יהיה נביאכם ה' במראה אליו אתודע בחלום אדבר בו פי' וכי במראה עין אליו אתודע כאלו בחלום אני מתראה לו ומדבר עמו ועל אותם התפילין שנראו למשה רבינו מתוך הכבוד חקרו רבותי' ז"ל מה היה כתיב בהן ומפרשי מי כעמך כישראל ומי גוי גדול ואלו הדברים קבלה הלכה למשה מסיני היו בידם ומקבלה פרשו שאי אפשר לדברים הללו להתפרש מן הדעת כלל

Comment: (+1) This is mentioned by the Rashba in his Chidushim on Berachos. In Peirushei Aggados the Rashba brings a lengthy explanation as to why the knot of the tefilin specifically was shown.

Answer (score 1):

It is meant allegorically.
Yet, Rav Moshe Takku believed that Hashem is corporeal, and that this midrash is literal, rather than allegorical. See here:
http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2010/01/rashi-and-rav-elyashiv.html?showComment=1265207473180#c1151988318870704459

Rav Moshe Taku was a 13th century Tosafist.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Taku

Comment: I'm not sure why the opinion of a single medieval scholar is relevant. He is outside the mainstream of Judaism. He even called R'Sadya Gaon a kofer for not being a corporealist!

Comment: it is relevant because: (i) it shows that there was not absolute consensus as to how to understand this gemara, and so is worthy of note; (ii) he is one that we *explicitly* know to be a corporealist by his own writings, but there were many others referred to by Rishonim who were corporealists. Yes, post-Rambam, modern mainstream Judaism rejects the corporeality of God.

Comment: @joshwaxman I don't think Judaism gives this opinion much consideration.

Comment: @joshwaxman it's not a Midrash it is a Gemara Berachot 6.

Comment: @HachamGabriel: It is a Midrash aggada which **appears** in a gemara. And of course contemporary Judaism does not give this opinion much consideration. The Rambam won the day, whether he was right or wrong as to the meaning of the midrash (and whether he was right or wrong as to God's corporeality).

Comment: *Yet, Rav Moshe Takku believed that Hashem is corporeal* source?

Comment: I'm giving this answer a downvote because it is slightly misleading. We do not follow the notion that G-d is corporeal like R. Moshe Taku. Let's not give people the wrong idea and think that mainstream Judaism believes this.

Comment: The wikipedia article about R' Moshe Takku itself includes an opinion that he did not believe that G-d is corporeal.

Comment: yes, it does, that Joseph Dan "takes issue with this widely held view of Taku's position". This seems couched as a daas yachid, where the widely held view is the opposite.

Comment: I hear, but knowing nothing about R' Moshe Takku, that reminds me of Rashi on Bereishis 3:8 about "hearing Hashem walking through the garden". Rashi says that's the simple reading. That does not imply to me that he thinks Hashem has feet, just that he objects to forced readings. I always read that Rashi similar to what Joseph Dan is saying.

Comment: But you should see what Rav Takku says first, to see whether it can be forced into that paradigm in the same way as Rashi. For instance, from that Wikipedia article, in the footnotes, "“This opinion of the minority of the Gaonim and the Karaites [that God does not have a body] is taken from the Kalam movement of the Muslims… You should know that everything that the Muslims said regarding this is all taken from the words of the Greeks and the Arameans.”"

Comment: _Still_ not having read his works, it seems to me that the quote you made is consistent with Joseph Dan's quote.

Answer (score 1):

Moshe Rabbeinu did not see the tefillin, but the knot since HaShem 'turned'.
The midrash aggadah in Berakhot 6a contains a remez, but to understand it, one has to understand what the tefillin are.

I am not going to explain this, however, the tefillin are two containers of Torah. Please note that Moshe Rabbeinu received two sets of lukhot on which the Torah was inscribed (not just the Aseret HaDibrot). These provede the remez (hint) as to the true meaning of the tefillin, and why Moshe was only shown the knot, but why the midrash aggaadah refers to both, but not the knot.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely because God has no form, is why Chazal explain this to be referring to Tefillin rather than about God Himself.

The Maharal in [Gur Arye](http://mobile.tora.ws/index.html?bgf=lnn(15308,476,0)) explains this piece. When Moshe asked to see God's glory that was asking to see His Tefillin itself. We find that Tefillin is called יקר and פאר. It is an adornment. He was told that he can't see the actual full glory but he will be shown and will perceive the knot of the Tefillin, which is a secondary glory. Rather than seeing the full-spread glory He will see the existence of it, tied and not spread. He will see as one sees from behind, in which it is enough to know that it's there while still not getting the full picture.